# Adding a horizontal scroll bar in selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, horizontal-scrolling, selectinput

Is it possible to add a horizontal scroll bar to a `selectInput` with a fixed number of items (e.g. size = 5)?

Some items are too long and will not show completely, and I don't want to change the width of the `selectInput`.

I tried adding it with:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-bound-input{overflow-x: scroll;}')))
```

but without success...
Is there any solution?

```
library(shiny) 
u <- fluidPage(   

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-bound-input{overflow-x: scroll;}'))),

  selectInput(inputId = "in", label = "Choose", choices = c('Short','A very short sentence.'), 
              selectize = F, size = 5, width = "150px")

)

s <- function(input,output){} 

shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

**Edit**: It seems to be browser dependent. E.g. in Opera and Chrome is a horizontal bar. In Firefox and IE not.

Comment: I get a horizontal scrollbar with your code, in Chrome.